# How do you use OpenAI Gym 'wrappers' with a custom Gym environment in Ray Tune?

Tags: python, tensorflow, openai-gym, ray

How do you use OpenAI Gym 'wrappers' with a custom Gym environment in [Ray Tune](https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/tune/index.html)?

Let's say I built a Python class called `CustomEnv` (similar to the '[CartPoleEnv](https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/master/gym/envs/classic_control/cartpole.py)' class used to create the OpenAI Gym `"CartPole-v1"` environment) to create my own (custom) reinforcement learning environment, and I am using `tune.run()` from [Ray Tune](https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/tune/index.html) (in Ray 2.1.0 with Python 3.9.15) to train an agent in my environment using the '[PPO](https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/rllib/rllib-algorithms.html)' algorithm:

```
import ray
from ray import tune
tune.run(
        "PPO",                         # 'PPO' algorithm
        config={"env": CustomEnv,      # custom class used to create an environment
            "framework": "tf2",
            "evaluation_interval": 100, 
            "evaluation_duration": 100,
            },
        checkpoint_freq = 100,             # Save checkpoint at every evaluation
        local_dir=checkpoint_dir,          # Save results to a local directory
        stop{"episode_reward_mean": 250},  # Stopping criterion
        )
```

This works fine, and I can use [TensorBoard](https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/get_started) to monitor training progress, etc., but as it turns out, learning is slow, so I want to try using 'wrappers' from Gym to scale observations, rewards, and/or actions, limit variance, and speed-up learning. So I've got an ObservationWrapper, a RewardWrapper, and an ActionWrapper to do that--for example, something like this (the exact nature of the scaling is not central to my question):

```
import gym

class ObservationWrapper(gym.ObservationWrapper):
    def __init__(self, env):
        super().__init__(env)
        self.o_min = 0.
        self.o_max = 5000.

    def observation(self, ob):
        # Normalize observations
        ob = (ob - self.o_min)/(self.o_max - self.o_min)
        return ob

class RewardWrapper(gym.RewardWrapper):
    def __init__(self, env):
        super().__init__(env)
        self.r_min = -500
        self.r_max = 100

    def reward(self, reward):
        # Scale rewards:
        reward = reward/(self.r_max - self.r_min)
        return reward

class ActionWrapper(gym.ActionWrapper):
    def __init__(self, env):
        super().__init__(env)

    def action(self, action):
        # Scale actions
        action = action/10
        return action
```

Wrappers like these work fine with my custom class when I create an instance of the class on my local machine and use it in traditional training loops, like this:

```
from my_file import CustomEnv

env = CustomEnv()
wrapped_env = ObservationWrapper(RewardWrapper(ActionWrapper(env)))
episodes = 10

for episode in range(1,episodes+1):
    obs = wrapped_env.reset()
    done = False
    score = 0
    
    while not done:
        action = wrapped_env.action_space.sample()
        obs, reward, done, info = wrapped_env.step(action)
        score += reward

    print(f'Episode: {episode},  Score: {score:.3f}')
```

My question is:  How can I use wrappers like these with my custom class (`CustomEnv`) and `ray.tune()`?  This particular method expects the value for "env" to be passed either (1) as a class (such as `CustomEnv`) or (2) as a string associated with a registered Gym environment (such as `"CartPole-v1"`), as I found out while trying various incorrect ways to pass a wrapped version of my custom class:

```
ValueError: >>> is an invalid env specifier. You can specify a custom env as either a class (e.g., YourEnvCls) or a registered env id (e.g., "your_env").
```

So I am not sure how to do it (assuming it is possible).  I would prefer to solve this problem without having to register my custom Gym environment, but I am open to any solution.

In learning about wrappers, I leveraged mostly '[Getting Started With OpenAI Gym: The Basic Building Blocks](https://blog.paperspace.com/getting-started-with-openai-gym/)' by Ayoosh Kathuria, and '[TF 2.0 for Reinforcement Learning](https://alexandervandekleut.github.io/gym-wrappers/): Gym Wrappers'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to answer my own question about how to get Ray's `tune.run()` to work with a wrapped custom class for a Gym environment.  The documentation for [Ray Environments](https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/rllib/rllib-env.html) was helpful.

The solution was to register the custom class through Ray.  Assuming you have defined your Gym wrappers (classes) as discussed above, it works like this:

```
from ray.tune.registry import register_env
from your_file import CustomEnv             # import your custom class

def env_creator(env_config):
    # wrap and return an instance of your custom class
    return ObservationWrapper(RewardWrapper(ActionWrapper(CustomEnv())))

# Choose a name and register your custom environment
register_env('WrappedCustomEnv-v0', env_creator)
```

Now, in `tune.run()`, you can submit the name of the registered instance as you would any other registered Gym environment:

```
import ray
from ray import tune

tune.run(
        "PPO",                          # 'PPO' algorithm (for example)
        config={"env": "WrappedCustomEnv-v0", # the registered instance
            #other options here as desired
            },
        # other options here as desired
        )
```

`tune.run()` will work with no errors--problem solved!